# Mapping over a sequence of Futures using cats Nested?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Using the Ammonite REPL I was able to reproduce this part of the cats `Nested` [code example](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/data/Nested.scala#L19):

```
@ import $ivy.`org.typelevel::cats-core:2.0.0`; import cats.Functor; import cats.data.Nested; import cats.implicits._; import scala.concurrent.Future;

@ val nested = Nested(List(Some(1), None))
nested: Nested[List, Option, Int] = Nested(List(Some(1), None))

@ nested.map(_.toString)
res2: Nested[List, Option, String] = Nested(List(Some("1"), None))
```

Hooray! This is working great. But why does `map` not exist when I'm trying to do the same thing over a `Future` of `Seq`uences?

```
@ val nestedFutureSeq = Nested(Future.successful(List(1)))
nestedFutureSeq: Nested[Future, List, Int] = Nested(Future(Success(List(1))))

@ nestedFutureSeq.map(_.toString)
cmd5.sc:1: value map is not a member of cats.data.Nested[scala.concurrent.Future,List,Int]
did you mean mapK?
val res5 = nestedFutureSeq.map(_.toString)
                           ^
Compilation Failed
```

Both `Future` and `Seq` define `map`, so it seems like this would be possible. Can I use `Nested` to do this and, if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` on **Nested** works if there is an instance of **Functor** for both types.
And the **Functor** of **Future** requires and `implicit` **ExecutionContext** in scope, since all methods in **Future** requires it.

So if you add a line like this *(or any other form of putting an implicit ec in scope)*:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

You will get your expected result.

```
nestedFutureSeq.map(_.toString)
// res: Nested[Future, List, String] = Nested(Future(Success(List(1))))
```